# why Integer value is not inserted in access database

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2007

Iam trying to insert integer value into access database but its giving me Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. error but in datagridview im putting a value but still show me this error

```
string Medicine_Name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString();
            string Dealer_name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Dealer_name"].Value.ToString();
            int Availability =Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Availability"].Value); 


                if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
                {
                    string connectionString = null;
                    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                     string cmd1 = "insert into Medicine_Available_Detail(Medicine_Name,Dealer_name,Availability) values(@Medicine_Name,@Dealer_name,@Availability)";
                      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);

                      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medicine_Name",Medicine_Name);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dealer_name", Dealer_name);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Availability", Availability);
 con.Open();
                    int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    if (n > 0)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully", "Data Inserted ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


                    }

                }
```

[image]

Comment: The error means that  `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Availability"].Value` returns `DBNull` which can not be converted (casted) to int. On which row does the error occur?

Comment: on Availability column and 2nd row error is occur last 15 days im trying to resolve this issue but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution on this i change my code dataGridView1_RowLeave to dataGridView1_CellValueChanged and its working fine

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
med_id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Med_id"].Value.ToString();

if (med_id == "")
{
med_id1 = 0;
}
else
{
med_id1 = Convert.ToInt32( dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Med_id"].Value.ToString());

}
if (med_id1 == 0)
{
try
{
string Medicine_Name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString();
string Dealer_name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Dealer_name"].Value.ToString();
int Availability = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Availability"].Value.ToString());
string cmd1 = "insert into Medicine_Available_Detail(Medicine_Name,Dealer_name,Availability) values(@Medicine_Name,@Dealer_name,@Availability)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medicine_Name", Medicine_Name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dealer_name", Dealer_name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Availability", Availability);
con.Open();
int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
if (n > 0)
{

MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully", "Data Inserted ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


}
Load_data();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}


}
else
{
string Medicine_Name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString();
string Dealer_name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Dealer_name"].Value.ToString();
int Availability = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Availability"].Value.ToString());
cmd = new OleDbCommand();

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "update Medicine_Available_Detail set Medicine_Name='" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString() + "',Dealer_name='" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Dealer_name"].Value.ToString() + "',Availability='" + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Availability"].Value.ToString())+ "'where Med_id=" + med_id1 + "";
con.Open();
int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
if (n > 0)
{

MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully", "Data Inserted ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


}
Load_data();
dataGridView1.Refresh();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "pencil" indicates that the row is being edited, thus - even with an entered value of 2 - the value of *Availability* can very well be null.

So your concept seems faulty; you should not attempt to insert data when `dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty` is *true* but when it is *false*.

Comment: i comment  if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
                { this part but still got same error

Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

and when i commented above part inserted value is repeated

Comment: Don't know your application, but it appears the `RowLeave` is not the event to use.

Comment: if  RowLeave is not the event to use. then how string value is inserted fine freind

Comment: That could be because you don't leave the row from any of those fields.

Comment: so any suggestion on what event should i right code?

Comment: I mostly use a save button.

Comment: dear friend i got a solution and update my ans also pls you also check